# Writing to Files

Tags: c, file, clion

I recently done a program and ended up getting wrong on my homework. I had all the right steps however, I was not supposed to do it from the command line but run it from the IDE (if that makes sense).

What I am supposed to do is go into the file "numbers.txt" and read the integers in it (there are numbers already in there). I am suppose to find the sum, product and the highest integer and output those to a text called "stat.txt". However, I am confused on how to do it from my compiler. I have both files in the same directory however when I run it in the compiler, it says "Can not read input file." and I have no idea how to use the compiler to just read the text files because I am so use to using the command line.

Here's my code (I could not get max to fit in with the code).

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int number = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int product = 1;
    int max = 0; 

    FILE *input, *output;
    input = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("stat.txt", "w");

    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("Can not read the input file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while ((fscanf(input, "%d", &number)) != EOF) {
            sum = sum + number;
            product = product * number;
        if (number > max){
            max = number;
        }
    }
    fprintf(output, "Sum : %d\n", sum);
    fprintf(output,"Product : %d\n", product);
    fprintf(output, "Largest: %d", max);
    fclose(input); fclose(output);
}
```

Comment: Guessing that you're supposed to run the code from the *[integrated development environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)* (IDE). The IDE should have project settings that allow you to specify the *working directory* and the *command line arguments*.

Comment: Did you mean run it from your IDE? Or did you mean run it from the compiler's debugger? Compilers run by compiling source codes and generating machine readable code. That's all it will do and issue ERRORS and WARNINGS when necessary.

Comment: Sorry, from the IDE. I will edit it right now.

Comment: I don't see how you can do it from a 'compiler', unless perhaps your IDE is the 'compiler'.  If you're getting "Can not read the input file" errors, it means that your program is not being run from the directory where the file is found, or perhaps you don't have permission to read it, but 'wrong directory' is more likely the problem. You should check the output file was opened too, though that's less likely to be a problem as it will be created. As long as at least some of the numbers in the file are positive (they're not all negative), your `max` will be OK. Find out where your `stat.txt` is.

Comment: stat.txt is in the same place where numbers.txt is. And yes, sorry for the confusion. I mean IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What IDE are you using? You are supplying fopen with a relative path to numbers.txt, it must exist in the same directory as the executable.

Either place numbers.txt into the same folder where your IDE builds the program, or supply it with an absolute path like '/home/username/Desktop/number.txt'

Comment: I am using CLion and they are in the same directory as where my .c programs are located.

Comment: ok, clion is great. However, is the executable in the same folder as the .c source files? Probably not.

Comment: You mean as put them where my ClionProjects are?

Comment: on my windows system: the source files are at c:/users/matthew/clionprojects/project_name    while the executables are at c:/users/matthew/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/<somevalue>/<somevalue>/Debug

Comment: I am on Mac. And numbers.txt is in the same directory. '/home/username/ClionProjects/ENEE140(the name where my programs are).

Comment: look for your executable in /home/username/.Clion12/system/generated/<somevalue>/<somevalue>/Debug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109483/discussion-between-soonpro-and-matthew-darnell).